# Impact of not running Cassandra repair on a time series data

Tags: cassandra

Data we store in Cassandra is pure time series with no manual deletes. Data gets deleted only by TTL.

For such use cases, is repair really needed? What is the impact of not running repair?

Answer (score 1):

1. Tobstoned data really deleted after gc_grace_seconds + compaction. if table with tombstoned data is not compacted, you will stack with this data, and it will cause performance degradation.
2. If you don't run repair within gc_grace period, dead data can live again. Here's datastax article on this (and why you need to run repairs regulary):

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_about_deletes_c.html

EDIT:

TTLed data isn't tombstoned on the time of the expire, but only when there's a compaction proccess (at least in 3.9). You will not see expired data, even when there's no tombstones.

So, if there is a problem with the node, and TTLed data isn't got it's tombstone on compaction, it will get one on the next compaction, or will be simply deleted. According to this, and the fact that the data is NEVER deleted and only expired, and you don't have any owerwrites to same key, you don't have to run repairs for data consistency.

And, regarding to all above, i will recommend to run repairs once in a while (with much higher interval between them), in case that something accidentally was written not using you write pass.

Comment: I don't think repair removed the tombstones; only compaction does. Deleted data can come up only when node that was down came back up. But in a case where I do not do any manual deletes, will NOT the node delete the data itself based on TTL?

Comment: Yes, repair doesn't remove tombstones, i didn't explained my self good, please review edited answer.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @nevsv. Can you define higher interval? Will it be days or weeks?

Comment: It depends how heavy your load is. It should be before your gc grace period, so try to run it once in that period (default 10 days). Repair operation not only repairs tombstones, but also inconsistent data (writes that failed on one node, but was written on "quorum", etc...). Since tombstones are not your problem, and these inconsistences will be fixed with read-repairs eventually, you don't even have to run repairs within gc grace period.

Answer (score 0):

If you set TTL, cassandra will mark the data with tombstone after the time exceeded. If you don't run repair regularly, huge tombstone will be generated and it will affect cassandra performance

> After the number of seconds since the column's creation exceeds the TTL value, TTL data is considered expired and is included in results. Expired data is marked with a tombstone after on the next read on the read path, but it remains for a maximum of gc_grace_seconds. After this amount of time, the tombstoned data is automatically removed during the normal compaction and repair processes

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_expire_c.html

Comment: In this case, I made sure the tombstones are not created in large numbers - by reducing the gc_grace_seconds accordingly

Comment: "Expired data is marked with a tombstone after on the next read" - it's marked with tombstone only on next compaction, tested in 3.9. Also if expired data is older than gc_grace on the time of compaction, it will be simply removed, without any tombstones created at all.